# MathML UpIntegrals

Tags: mathml

I am new to html, css and mathml but can now produce mathematics rendered in Firefox pretty well, if slowly. My problem is how to use the up integral symbols in the STIX fonts.

```
<mo>&#x222b;</mo>
```

produces a slanted symbol by default. Using fontfamily="STIXIntegralsUp" has no effect on Firefox but produces an up integral symbol in other browsers. I also have STIXMath fonts installed but the up integral symbols do not have a unicode. How do I use these symbols without a unicode?

In short, how do I produce an up integral symbol in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

> In short, how do I produce an up integral symbol in Firefox?

```
<math display="block" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mo>∫</mo></math>
```

If you don't want the equation centered,

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mstyle displaystyle="true"><mo>∫</mo></mstyle></math>
```

## Update

> Using fontfamily="STIXIntegralsUp" has no effect on Firefox but produces an up integral symbol in other browsers.

`fontfamily` are deprecated as you can check in http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter3.html. Firefox was update based on the new specification but others browsers weren't.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the up integral in your code becomes a slanted integral when rendered in Firefox on my system. A Mac running Yosemite with Firefox 38.0.1. My ref to fontfamily was in a CSS code:                                                                                                            math
{
    font-family: "STIXIntegralsUp", "STIXGeneral";
}